A coworker says I’m being rude—only to him. How should I handle this?
I’ve been working in the IT department of my company for about two years now. Six months ago, a new coworker, John (not his real name), was hired to replace me as team lead because my manager felt it was the right decision. Initially, I wasn’t aware of this change. I only discovered it after a couple of months, when I noticed conflicts in decision-making within the project. At that point, I asked for clarification and was informed that John had officially replaced me.
I admit that, for the first week or so, I was confused, frustrated, and disappointed by the decision. However, I quickly decided to accept the situation, as it allowed me to shed some responsibilities and focus on my role as a subordinate rather than a leader.
During the first couple of months, there was quite a bit of tension between John and me. This was largely because neither of us was aware of the change in leadership—both of us thought we were in charge. After a meeting with my manager to clear things up, I immediately adjusted my behavior. Since then, I’ve done everything to support John, respect his decisions, and avoid any friction. I’ve made sure to respond quickly to his requests, follow his directions without argument, and provide assistance with legacy code, as I have more experience with the project. We even take breaks, eat lunch, and share jokes together in our group chat. I truly thought the tensions were behind us.
I’ve come to terms with the management’s decision to replace me, and I no longer want or need the lead role. I trust my manager’s judgment and just want to focus on doing my current job well without added stress.
However, a few days ago, I was called into a meeting, with my manager present, where John claimed that I continue to be rude to him. No one else on the team—around 40 people—has ever told me that I’m rude to them. In fact, I’ve never had any issues with any other coworkers. John, however, insists that my behavior is still problematic, and my manager even called me privately afterward, asking me to stop acting this way toward John.
I’ve tried to resolve this. I had a one-on-one meeting with John where I reassured him that I have nothing against him, but despite this, he still perceives me as rude. To make things worse, my manager—who has known me for two years—now seems to believe John's version of events over mine. This feels extremely frustrating and unfair, especially since I’ve been doing everything I can to maintain a positive working relationship with John.
How should I handle this situation where only one coworker, and particularly a new one, perceives me as rude, while no one else does?
EDIT: Let me clarify a few things:
Yes, it took a couple of months for me to realize that John had replaced me as the team lead. No one officially informed me right away, and I only found out during project decision conflicts. Once clarified, I adjusted to the new situation.
I already acknowledged the initial tension and have since made significant efforts to change my behavior. I’ve fully embraced my subordinate role, even meeting with John privately to assure him that I hold no grudge. Despite this, John continues to perceive me as rude, which is the core issue here.
My main question is how to handle this situation now that it feels like my efforts to resolve things are not being recognized, and my manager seems to side with John despite our long-standing working relationship.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The edit to this question unfortunately has made the answers, particularly the accepted one, quite detached from the question – the central point and crux of the answer (that you were team leader and were replaced in that position) is now not mentioned in the question at all. When you read the accepted answer now, the conclusion “You should leave” seems insanely over the top based on what the question says, quite different from the impression you get if you read the original question.

I agree with the general consensus of rolling back, and that the edit (although not vandalizing) does shift the scope and nature of the question farther than any edit or clarification to a Q should do. @ohno I think there are better ways to edit this or shorten it without removing the relevant information or changing the original Q too much. If your question is now a different one, please post a new question with a new focus. Rolling back...

If i edited the question by removing really really specific data about my current situation is because i'm really feeling in a unsafe position. I dont have proof of it but things are escalating really quickly now and wanted to conceal as much as possible. I'm not allowed to delete the question now and i don't really know how to anonimize it. I think is too late now, thanks for being sensitive about the situation... i didnt expect all such visibility. I'm having a really bad time now

@ohno some suggestions and observations for you. think twice before posting next time and which details you are ok sharing with (genuine suggestion). The system wont allow deleting cause you have several valuable answers with positive score. I removed this Q from HNQ to avoid "such visibility", that's why you got much attention here, the post hit HNQ. I understand what you feel, but there has to be a compromise/balance between what you edit and the Q/answers; the edit you did damaged the post, its readability and the meaning of the answers given.

@ohno [cont.] so, I hope you see why its not something done lightly. However, there's a process to disassociate/anon your post. It will have to be carried out by you (contacting SE and asking for that). The end result is this post not linking to your profile... again, think twice next time before posting. Don't want to be negative but remember that what you upload on internet stays there (i.e., even if disassociated, I bet waybackmachine and similar tools will show your name)

You should leave.
Or rather, you should have left the instant that you discovered you'd been silently replaced as team lead months after the fact. That's utterly insane institutional behavior, and no one should put up with it.
More importantly, it's a flag that you've lost the organization's trust, and are effectively being pushed out of the organization's power structure. In a situation like that you really need to find a new job and start fresh. Top professionals don't stick around in an organization at the point that they start getting demoted (and even moreso when the organization isn't honest with them about it).
The interpersonal static with the new lead is an unavoidable after-effect of that. No one in that position is going to be comfortable with the old lead hanging around, and witlessly thinking they're the lead to boot. There will inevitably be some reason to push you further away.
You're on the exit slide at this organization, get out and stabilize elsewhere.

That's an interesting point of view. I've been promoted to lead (and with a meeting where all the rest of the team was present) when my old team lead left. I was not aware that my role was temporary leading until a new one was found. My manager maybe deliberately (or maybe not) omitted this detail. --- when the new guy arrived, nobody knew he was the new lead... everyone was surprised as well when i shared this new found info

but thanks for the suggestion, i might prepare soon indeed to settle elsewhere.

@ohno had the thought not even occurred to you?!

here they make meetings for everything, ironically they could make some for when the coffe is finished or when it is refilled. When this 'incident' occurred... there was completely no meetings. I've checked with the rest of the team... nobody knew it until i directly asked to my manager what was happening

guys, i'm confused and surprised of this absurd situation as well. its difficult to determine all the office situations since its hybrid and there's people that doesnt even show up at the office for weeks.

I can't agree with the strict "you should leave" of this answer, after all not everyone can just walk in to another job.  However I do agree that this indicates your organisation doesn't trust you.  Prior to replacing someone as lead they should have discussed their expectations and explained how the employee wasn't meeting them.  In addition not even letting the person know they had been demoted and having a ex-lead who doesn't know they have been demoted and a team who doesn't know the new hire is now their lead is either massively incompetent or utterly spineless.

@EricNolan... or, indeed, both!

@ohno: If you feel that you want a real challenge, then remain in the company and prove them that you can continue to be there in spite of their mistreatment towards you. However, this "challenge" can backfire against you in many unforeseeable ways, and all of them can be very destructive for your life. I talk from personal experience. I was somehow an exception, because I succeeded to end up with some kind of personal benefit (in addition, to losing money, my health, life in general...). So overall, it is REALLY better for you to find a new job very quickly, and never regret leaving.

@ohno: And the fact that that organization does not trust you, is probably the small problem. The other problems are: 1) The company makes efforts to discredit and destroy you personally and professionally; 2) You cannot trust them - and you should never trust them again. And in the absence of trust, how can you continue being there?

I enjoy challenges with code, not with people. If I wanted to challenge people, I would have chosen to be an Olympic athlete! ahhaahha :D i just want to work as what im passionate (its ben more than 10 years now) and be sure i can pay loan and and sustain my family at the end of the month. Not asking for the moon i hope

"No one in that position is going to be comfortable with the old lead hanging around, and witlessly thinking they're the lead to boot. There will inevitably be some reason to push you further away." - no, a reasonable person would understand the problem and deal with it.

I am normally not a big fan of "You should leave" answers, but this is the appropriate answer. There is little career growth here.

@EricNolan hey, your comment here in my eyes looks like an answer in comments, which is something we don't encourage to do (post an answer instead, upvote, downvote, etc). Comments are not for answering

@EricNolan "after all not everyone can just walk in to another job" - the OP has the advantage of not having been fired, so there is plenty of time to brush up the resume and try interviewing at other places at leisure without too much of a time pressure.

Let's be clear about the sequence of events here:

You were promoted to team lead at some point. Your manager (presumably) told you that fact.
They hired John, told him that he's the new lead, and did not tell you.
They allowed you to persist in this belief for months.
Several parts of your question and comments strongly imply that you believe your manager intentionally failed to inform you.
You are now being told that John think's you're "rude," and in the comments you indicate that the only specific complaint he was able to come up with was "not smiling enough."
Your manager has sided with John despite this lack of detail.

This is a clear-cut example of constructive dismissal, a process in which a workplace is made unbearable in the hopes that you quit on your own so that they do not have to fire you. At the same time, they are also recording "problems" with you so that they can prepare a case to fire you if you do not take the hint. In a few more weeks or possibly a month or two, they will likely give you a formal written reprimand. I do not know what country you are in or what your local labor laws say, but this process will eventually end in your termination one way or another.
The mention of "smiling" is also concerning for another reason: When deployed against women, it is a common form of sexism. You did not specify your gender, but I would frankly be pretty surprised if someone made this complaint against a man. If you are indeed a woman, this may serve as concrete evidence of sexual discrimination by your employer.
You have a few different options at this point:

Find a new job now, and move on with your life.
File a complaint with whoever is in charge of labor law in your country.

These are not mutually exclusive - if you are planning to file a complaint, you should also be planning to find your next place of work, and in fact it is probably wise to start with that and file the complaint after your employment situation is less precarious. It may also be a good idea to consult an employment lawyer, since they can give advice more specifically tailored to your individual situation.
In the meantime, document absolutely everything that John or your manager says to you that is in any way relevant to this situation. Include the date, the time, any other people present, and as much of the precise wording as you can remember. Also document as much as you can remember of what has already been said. Keep these notes somewhere you'll be able to access them after you are terminated - do not keep them in the company's files or on a company-owned device.


@Asherah, i asked him and he couldnt recall a specific episode. Told me that i dont smile enough .. which is just absurd to hear.

This is your response to the comment, "Has he given examples of what he perceives as rude behaviour?".
The real challenge you're going to have is that someone in a leadership role is making direct statements about you to your boss, but is being purposely indirect when you challenge those statements.  This is a game that you can't win, friend.
Even though you feel that you're in a state where you defer to this guy's authority, you make him feel insecure.  You've described situations whereas you seem to have pointed out conflicts.  You may have been 100% on point as far as what you demonstrated, and in some cases this alone is enough to rattle  such a person like "John".  He can't fire you directly, but he is poisoning your situation.  Your boss has shown you that as far as this is concerned, you're on your own.
Tip your hat, and bounce.

The fact that you have been "silently" replaced is a measure of the toxicity or the chaos in your organization. Or a bit of these two.
On its own, if this is a matter of the organization just not being a good one, it is up to you to decide if you can live with this. From what you are saying - you are fine with the change (I had this happening once and was also ultimately happy with the change, after a brief ego trip).
The fact that your (new) manager and your (old) manager team up to say that you are being rude is a major warning sign (a blinking one). You will be extremely uncomfortable in that company and leaving may be the best option.
Since your question is "how to handle this situation", one answer I have is "not with HR" because you have two layers of management against you.

as you said, at the beginning i was like "what the f...?" but then (roughly after a week) i had sooo much less meeting calls, reports to present to the higher ones. Less responsibilities to meet and doing not anymor extra work hours (unpaid) to meet the deadlines of these duties. I was indeed relieved... thats why i dont understand why this "witch hunting" is keeping going

I completely get what you are saying - and I had the same reaction after some time. Thus my first paragraph. The second is what is worrisome - they may not like you anymore after the perceived "fight for power"?

im afraid i cant answer this right now.

@ohno while the lessened responsibility might be worth the trade - the question for me is... how can you trust anything from them? They demoted you (without a pay drop? check your paystubs? I assume a team lead gets paid more?) and are actively working against you and, presumably, all of this is being done without a paper trail? What is the team structure on paper? Your position on paper? I don't know how you can trust them at this point as they are clearly off the rails...

You need to start interviewing with other companies. You said you have a loan and you need to support your family. Your precarious financial situation is precisely the reason why you need to start getting the ball running with other companies.
You also said you've been working there for 10+ years. This is a long time. Your CV is out of date. Your interviewing skills are rusty. It will take time for you to get used to it again. If you get fired, it will be very hard for you to find another job in a timely manner. You can't afford to wait. And your family can't either.
And it doesn't matter what the new team lead said. May be he's insecure about his new position. Or may be he resents that your co-workers still look up to you because you still know the code base the best. Whatever the reason is, you won't ever really know what it is, and you won't ever be able to control how he feels about you.
And your boss will side with the team lead. If I was your boss and if I had to choose between a new team lead and an individual contributor, I would choose the team lead 100% of the time. Also, if I was your boss, I would be super embarrassed about the way I had treated you earlier. But that's not going to help you, most likely, based on your boss's past behavior, letting you go or pushing you out is probably the most likely solution to sweep the entire incident under the rug.
Also if you start interviewing and if someone makes you an offer, you don't have to accept it. My point is. You just need to get the ball running. If you get offers from other companies, you won't feel as trapped anymore. And in the mean time, have your family live below their means, don't get into any more debt, and build up an emergency fund.

Personally, I would tell my manager about the ongoing bad feelings, and ask if he could speak to the new team lead about what happened and calm things down, telling them that you really don't blame them for the change and they need to get over their fear that you do. Meanwhile, go out of your way not to show resentment about the role change. If that means an extra effort to smile for a few weeks, that may be worth doing.
Most such misunderstandings can be smoothed out, so if you are otherwise still enjoying the job I would not be looking at interviewing elsewhere yet. I might ask about whether there was something independent, or with another team, you could do for a while until the new lead stops being overly defensive, but hopefully that isn't necessary.
Your manager handled this badly. If they are unwilling to help fix it, actually changing departments might be worth considering.

I'm not sure the manager is an ally here, they've been obvious in their bias against OP pretty strongly at this point. They like the new team lead, the new TL wants OP gone, and they want to keep the new TL happy.

I'm not so sure they want the op gone. Changing assignment does not necessarily indicate disapproval.
